# Install a2enmod in XAMPP ubuntu and mac os x

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, flask, xampp

I want to deploy flask project on XAMPP in MAC or Ubuntu.

[Reference URL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) to deploy flask project

Getting error while running this command - **sudo a2enmod wsgi**

**Error** - `sudo: a2enmod: command not found`

Comment: I think that command just symlink corresponding mod from mods-available to mods-enabled, you can just manually do that.

Comment: @YOU: How to do that ? I don't have any idea

Comment: ln -s mods-available/wsgi.conf mods-enabled/wsgi.conf from your /etc/apache2 directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to have apache2 (the webserver) installed for this command.

Comment: Why I need to install apache2. I have already install XAMPP on my machine. Does it not possibile onto XAMPP ?

Comment: How did you install xampp? Could be it's not in your path

Comment: I followed these steps http://vichargrave.com/how-to-install-xampp-on-mac-os-x-step-by-step/

Comment: So just with the installer?